# Truncate text on screen resize/mobile with ability to expand text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, truncate

I have a fiddle located here, https://jsfiddle.net/patricksharer/g43t1bnh/3/ where I have been trying to use the trunk8 jquery plugin to shrink a section of text on my page when viewed on mobile. I have the truncation working fine but when you click the ..red more link to try and expand the text, nothing happens. Can someone take a look at my code to see what I have done wrong?

The section in which I am trying to truncate is in,

```
<div class="grid-100 mobile-grid-100 main-photo-description">
     <p class="t8-toggle">Here's a couple of SHJ's cars at the Penske race shop in NC. This photo was taken while on tour with www.GaragePassShopTours.com</p>
</div>
```

Thanks as always you beautiful Stackoverflow people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with using `live` since it was [deprecated as of 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Adjust to a `click` function like:

```
$('#read-more').click(function (event) {
   $(this).parent().trunk8('revert').append(' <a id="read-less" href="#">read less</a>');
   return false;
});
```

Or use `on` like:

```
$('#read-more').on('click', function (event) {
   $(this).parent().trunk8('revert').append(' <a id="read-less" href="#">read less</a>');
   return false;
});
```

Update for the `read-less`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#read-less', function (event) {
     $(this).parent().trunk8(); 
     return false;
});
```

Comment: You'll likely need to tie to `document` then. Like `$(document).on('click'...)` since it's not already in the DOM

Comment: You rock! Thanks that was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually the creator of trunk8 so I feel obligated to find out what's going wrong.

It looks like you've copied the example from http://jrvis.com/trunk8/#toggle which was written for an older version of jQuery. The `live` method has been deprecated in favor of `on`. To confirm this, I kept your code exactly the same but changed the version of jQuery to something older than 1.9: https://jsfiddle.net/g43t1bnh/10/ and it works.

I've also updated my website to use `on` instead of `live` to prevent others from having this issue.

Here's a rewritten version that uses the event delegation compatible with jQuery 2.1.3: https://jsfiddle.net/g43t1bnh/8/

As others have noted, `#read-less` doesn't exist at the time of execution, so you need to bind the click event handler to some other ancestor element for the delegation to work. The `document` is used for this purpose. In my version linked above, I use delegation in both more/less bindings for consistency even though it's only necessary in the less case.

Comment: Now that's what I call support!

Comment: Thanks @Rick Viscomi. I can say that your plugin offered the best solution out there for my problem. camelCase is right, excellent support. I am very new to javascript so this had my head spinning but your explanation was perfectly clear and easy to understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you've found it useful. Should you need it, you can also get help with the plugin at https://github.com/rviscomi/trunk8/issues

Answer (score 2):

You are using the new version of `jquery` so the `live` function is not supported use `on` instead

`$('#read-more').on('click')`

but for the `read-less` button to work you have to change it to

`$(document).on('click',"#read-less")`

which is a common pattern for events to work on dynamically added elements.

Here is a working [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/g43t1bnh/9/).